# How come additional rows aren't being shown when button is clicked in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my code:

```
namespace UpdateDataGridView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        List<Apple> apples = new List<Apple>();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            apples.Add(new Apple { Color = "Red"});
            dataGridView1.DataSource = apples;
        }
    }
    public class Apple
    {
        public string Color { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am expecting a new row to be added to the dataridview every time the button is pressed.

I am not sure why this is not happening and I don't know how to achieve this. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# DataGridView not updated when datasource is changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758577/c-sharp-datagridview-not-updated-when-datasource-is-changed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to emit event for datagrid redraw. The simplest way, if your DataSource isn't big is next:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apples.Add(new Apple { Color = "Red"});
        dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = apples;
    }
```

If your collection is too big, you'd  better to change your container from List to ObservableCollection

```
ObservableCollection<Apple> apples = new ObservableCollection<Apple>();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        apples.Add(new Apple { Color = "Red"});
        dataGridView1.DataSource = apples;
    }
```

In your code, you can use ObservableCollection just like List, but it will tell your datagrid about changing items in your apples container

Comment: `dataGridView1.DataSource = null; ` <- This works     `ObservableCollection<Apple> apples = new ObservableCollection<Apple>();` <- I couldn't get this to work.

Comment: Yeah. You right. ObservableCollection<T> will not work. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16695885/binding-listt-to-datagridview-in-winform is the answer for your question. They use BindingList<T> what works fine

Answer (score 0):

Like many UI frameworks, Forms does not automatically redraw itself - it therefore must be told (often explicitly) when data has been changed and that it needs to refresh. Try calling [`datagridview1.Refresh()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.refresh(v=vs.110).aspx) at the end of your event handler.

Comment: '            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                apples.Add(new Apple { Color = "Red"});
                dataGridView1.DataSource = apples;
                dataGridView1.Refresh();
            }` Is this what you meant? Because when I do this it doesn't work.