# C# DataGridView control not updated when underlying MySQL database contents change

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview

I am using a data-bound datagridview (`sbDataGridView`) control in an Windows Form based C# desktop application.
Loading data from the database is working fine and all the values are displayed correctly.
But when simulating a change of the data in the database by manually adding some rows, this change is not automatically reflected by the datagridview control. Is there a way to make the control aware of the change and update itself automatically?
I've already added some time which performs the following tasks, but none of them worked...

```
    private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        // tBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        // sBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        // sbBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        sbDataGridView.DataSource = null;
        sbDataGridView.DataSource = sbBindingSource;

        //MessageBox.Show("Tick");
        //sbBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        //tBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
        //sBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);

        //sbDataGridView.Refresh();
        //sbDataGridView.Invalidate();

        //sDataSet.Reset();
        //tTableAdapter.Fill(sDataSet.t);
        //sTableAdapter.Fill(sDataSet.s);
        //sbTableAdapter.Fill(sDataSet.sb);
        //sbDataGridView.Invalidate();
    }
```

On the `Form_Load` method I have a line `RefreshTimer.Start()`.
If uncommenting the MessageBox line, the MessageBox is shown every second. The timer is currently set to elapse every second.

(I've tried all and some of the above in various orders...)
Any ideas what's wrong here?

I already tried the "dirty" solution from [C# DataGridView not updated when datasource is changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758577/c-sharp-datagridview-not-updated-when-datasource-is-changed), but that did not work either.

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: you need to show what the method signature looks like in the code you posted.. also how are you triggering the update to go out and make the call to the database again.. also this being a windows application how is it supposed to know about any changes to the database..  and the Dirty  way should work.. doesn't look like you're doing anything close to that..

Comment: You are right. I did not write when the function calls are run. I'm using a timer and the method signature is: `private void RefreshTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Regarding the dirty way, I also included the calls in the timer method and the DGV did not update. Only when closing the application and re-starting it, the new data were available.

Comment: Also, make sure that if your data grid is in a container control (eg. Panel, Group Box) that you refresh that control as well.

Comment: @TomS you need to edit the question and post the relevant code.. sounds like you are using the Timer_Tick event incorrectly would be my guess.. you need to show all relevant code as it pertains to your issue.. also what is the interval that the polling happens in regards to the timer..? personally I would test this code using a `Refresh` button and see if things work..then move it to a timer

Comment: After closing Visual Studio, rebooting the PC and restarting Visual Studio, the "dirty" solution also works. Now it's easier to debug. Thanks for your help!